# Error while playing the video file from embedded resource

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I  am developing vb.net Windows application for playing the video file.

I have added a video file in  embedded resource this way:

> Project->Properties. Then select the "Resources" tab. Next Select "Add
>   Rersource"->"From Existing File".

I am trying to play the file, buts its giving run time error on the line

```
 Dim myByte As Byte = myStream.ReadByte
```

Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   Dim aPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0).FullyQualifiedName)
    Dim myStream As Stream
    myStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("111.mp4")
    Dim myFileStream As New FileStream("111.mp4", FileMode.Create)
    Dim myFileBinary As New BinaryWriter(myFileStream)
    Try
        Dim myByte As Byte = myStream.ReadByte
        While Not myByte = -1
            myFileBinary.Write(myByte)
            myByte = myStream.ReadByte
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        myFileStream.Close()
    End Try

    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Path.Combine(aPath, "111.mp4")
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = True


End Sub
```

am I missing any step ?

Comment: It would appear that there is no manifest resource with that name to get, hence the result of `GetManifestResourceStream` is `Nothing`.  Is there any particular reason that you're not just adding the resource via the Resources page of the project properties and then getting it via `My.Resources`?

Comment: In fact you are using My.Resources. So you don't need to read the resource from assembly. Your file is stored in a byte array property of `My.resources` and you can simply save the resource using `File.WriteAllBytes` and use it as I did in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are using `My.Resources`. So you don't need to read the resource from assembly.

You can simply read and use it this way:

```
Dim FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "video.wmv")
If (Not File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, My.Resources.video)
End If

AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = FilePath
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

The if part is to check if the file exists and extracted before so we don't need to extract it again.

Comment: I had missed the part of your question  that you said you are adding the file this way:  `Project->Properties. Then select the "Resources" tab. Next Select "Add Rersource"->"From Existing File".` I edited the question to make it more readable. Also I edited the answer, so while the original answer is really useful when you are using embedded resources, but neglect previous discussions and just apply above answer :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts... Its working fine now... Its will be nice if you give me suggestion in small problem which occurred while implementing above thing...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738401/how-to-play-videos-one-by-one-videos-in-vb-net-from-embedded-resource

Comment: You are welcome :) I'll take a look that question :)

Comment: There is an answer for that question. You can use it :)