# How to play videos one by one videos in vb.net from embedded resource

Tags: vb.net, video

I am developing vb.net Windows application for playing the video file.

I have added a video files in embedded resource in this way:

> Project->Properties. Then select the "Resources" tab. Next Select "Add Resource"->"From Existing File".

I am able to success with playing the one video, but I want to play more than one video. (I have 5 more videos in Resource)

I  want to run another video once first one gets finished...

Here is my code which plays single video.

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "full"

    Dim FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "video.wmv")
    If (Not File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
        File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, My.Resources.My_video_file_name)
    End If

    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = FilePath
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

I want to play the video one after one, either by creating the playlist or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playlist for n files

```
Dim playlist As WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist")
playlist.appendItem(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(FilePath_1))
playlist.appendItem(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(FilePath_2))
...
playlist.appendItem(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(FilePath_n))
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = playlist
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

If you don't want to use a playlist you can achieve the same using the PlayStateChange event of the player.

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim file_counter As Integer
Private Sub Start_Playlist(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "video1.mp4")
    If (Not File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
        File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, My.Resources.video1)
    End If
    file_counter = 1
    PlayVideo()
End Sub
Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange
    If (AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded) Then
        Select Case file_counter
            Case 1
                FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "video2.mp4")
                If (Not File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
                    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, My.Resources.video2)
                End If
            Case 2
                FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "video3.mp4")
                If (Not File.Exists(FilePath)) Then
                    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, My.Resources.video3)
                End If
            ...
            Case Else
                FilePath = ""
        End Select
        If (Not FilePath.Equals("")) Then
            file_counter += 1
            Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf PlayVideo))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PlayVideo()
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = FilePath
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works smooth... but I have problem of the size of the video... I have 5 videos that have size of 1 GB collectively... Its gives an error ->Unable to write to output file 'C:\Users\Server\Desktop\Temp\VideoToEXE\playerwithvideo\EmbdedVideoInexe\EmbdedVideoInexe\obj\x86\Debug\EmbdedVideoInexe.exe': Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.  EmbdedVideoInexe what can I do in this...

Comment: When does the error appear? What are your system specs?

Comment: It works fine upto 400 MB videos... When I add one more video of 180 MB it start showing the above error... I have i3 processor with 8 GB RAM having Windows 7 Professional...

Comment: The error appears when you add the video to the resources?

Comment: Enough space on the hdd? You could try changing target framework and cpu to 4.5.2 and x64. That are my settings. If that doesn't work I'm afraid that I can't help you.